# Replace full html anchor with another html anchor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have an anchor tag

```
<a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefLockProposal" onclick="" href="javascript:void(0)">Locking</a>
```

I have to replace this anchor tag with following

```
var TempHtml= "<a class='contextMenuInnerItem' onclick='LockProposal(" + PKProposalId + ", 1)' href='javascript:void(0)'>Lock</a>"
```

I did this

```
htmlString=htmlString.replace("<a class='contextMenuInnerItem hrefLockProposal' onclick='' href='javascript:void(0)'>Locking</a>",TempHtml);
```

The htmlString is containing a very large amount of string which is coming from the database.

This is my htmlString which is coming from the database

```
<div><ul class="pmenubar"><li><div class="trigger" style="color:gray;border-right:0px; font-size:12px;" onclick=""></div><ul class="contextMenuInner"><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,11,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Settings</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,23,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Details</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,17,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Add Products</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,18,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">QuickSpec</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefReportProposal" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,19,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Print Setup</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefReportProposal" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,44,2);" href="javascript:void(0)">Print</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefExportProposal" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,22,0);" href="javascript:void(0)">Export</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefCopyProposal" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,24,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Duplicate</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefReportProposal" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,45,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Preview</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,52,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Print Setup (Beta)</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,53,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">QuickSpec(Old)</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,43,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Add Products(Old)</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem" onclick="RedirectPage(ProposalId,49,1);" href="javascript:void(0)">Details(Old)</a></li><li><a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefDeleteProposal" onclick="RemoveProposal(ProposalId)" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a></li><li id="ancLockProposal">**<a class="contextMenuInnerItem hrefLockProposal" onclick="" href="javascript:void(0)">Locking</a>**</li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

As you can see the last anchor tag in htmlString is the same I want to replace.How to achieve this?Kindly help.

Comment: Your parameters in `replace` should be strings.

Comment: . . .so you replaced and then what happened

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk Yes they are strings only.I corrected the code now.

Comment: In your `htmlString` you're using quotes, and in your TempHtml you're using apostrophes for attributes values.

Comment: @Arjuna It's giving me the same htmlString with no replacement.But if I replace any element like "li" with TempHtml or any anchor tag text like "Lock" with TempHtml,then it goes fine and replaces the content.But the same is not happening for what i want.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) to replace all occurences

Comment: @Arjuna I did this in console

htmlString=htmlString.replace(/<a class='contextMenuInnerItem hrefLockProposal' onclick='' href='javascript:void(0)'>Locking<\/a>/g,TempHtml);

But still it is showing me the same htmlString . :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last li element, that contains the anchor tag you want to replace, first empty that and then appens the anchor tag you want to add.

```
$("#ancLockProposal").empty();
$("$ancLockProposal").append("<a class='contextMenuInnerItem' 
   onclick='LockProposal(" + PKProposalId + ", 1)' href='javascript:void(0)'>Lock</a>");
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the following change:

```
htmlString=htmlString.replace(/<a class='contextMenuInnerItem hrefLockProposal' onclick='' href='javascript:void(0)'>Locking<\/a>/g,TempHtml);
```

Comment: No this is not working for me still.I checked in console and found out the same htmlString value. :P

Comment: I got the solution . Instead of replacing the part of a string coming from the database ,we can first empty the "li" under which the replaceable "a" is present.

I did this :-

    $("#ancLockProposal").empty(); //empty the parent "li" of replaceable "a" tag.
    $("#ancLockProposal").append(TempHtml);//After emptying , append the string by which you have to replace .Here it is TempHtml.

Comment: if that works for you, then post your answer to this question and mark it as the accepted answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use replace. Since you flagged this as jquery:

```
$('#ancLocProposal').next('a').text('Lock').click( function(){ LockProposal(PKProposalId, 1); } );
```

Possibly you'll need to use a closure, depending on scope/usage of PKProposalId:

```
(function(PKProposalId){$('#ancLocProposal').next('a').text('Lock').click( function(){ LockProposal(PKProposalId, 1); } );})(PKProposalId);
```

.. or you work with data-attributes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it get last anchor tag object in your div tag**

```
var totalACount= $('div a').length-1;
var lastAncher = $('div a:eq('+totalACount+')'); 
alert($(lastAncher).attr("href"));
```

you can access class,id,onclick any thing you want, if attribute is exist in anchor tag.
after accessing object you can replace object.